# How to clone properly Object class?

Tags: java, copy, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a POJO class that contains string fields and also a Map.
I read the Joshua Bloch Effective Java fragment about cloning objects, but this case I think is not so trivial.
I have a few POJOs, and I wanted to clone them using Copy Constructor approach, but I don't know how can I clone map which as value has an object ?

I know that this Object may be a simple immutable object, for example a String class, but sometimes it may be a completely different POJO, or even list or map. The onyl way which I think it may work is to do some checks in constructor using instanceof, but It's ugly (I would have to do check for List, Map, and every POJO right?).

Maybe I should change my approach to implement Cloneable interface?

I also saw a cloning method with serialization, but I think that this is also ugly solution, and it's performance would be worst then for example when using Copy Constructor approach.

Can you give me an advise how should I clone my POJOs?

Comment: Why would you clone them in the first place? Especially if you don't even know what type they are. You won't be able to modify them anyway since you don't even know their type.

Comment: I've never used `clone()` in production code in 18 years.

Comment: Why ? Because I have a POJO "A" which have a list of POJOs "B" with different properties, and I want to have completely different objects, a new copy. I just need it, because I want to create few instances of that pojo "A". Those POJOs "A" should have different values in POJOs "B", and if POJOs "A" will have reference to the same "B" POJO, then I won't be able to set different values in different POJOs "A"

Answer (score 0):

You could check `Apache Commons` [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#cloneBean(java.lang.Object)) . It has `cloneBean(Object bean)` method which will clone all properties even the class does not implement `Cloneable` interface.

Comment: So, you are assuming that the objects are JavaBeans?

Comment: The assumption is correct, because they are JavaBeans, however I already tried that, and it didn't worked, because JavaBeans which were properties of a Main JavaBeans weren't cloned. Let's say I have JB called "Main" which have field to the second JB called "Property". I have cloned JB "Main" few times and they had reference to the same "Property" JB as the original "Main" JavaBean.

Comment: From the docs:
Note: this method creates a shallow clone. In other words, any objects referred to by the bean are shared with the clone rather than being cloned in turn.